# React - Render Components based on Array - how to include functions from parent in mongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I want to store a props value in my MongoDB that is assigned to a parent function so that I can render components based on that array and every component has its own function.

I have a JSON like this that I got from my mongoDB and then store in `this.state.people`

```
{

    "_id": "60496f4e6478022895c0b1da",
    "name": "Peter",
    "imagepath": "./img/Peter.png",

},
{
    "_id": "60496f4e6478022895c0b1da",
    "name": "Tim",
    "imagepath": "./img/Tim.png",
}
```

I pass the state down to a child-component and render the components with:

```
{props.people.map( result =>
  <PeopleComponent
  key={result._id}
  name={result.name}
  imagepath={result.imagepath}
  />
)}
```

works good so far.

now my problem that I can't solve:
in my parent-component App.js I have the functions `doSomethingWithPeter()` and `doSomethingWithTim()`. how do I include those functions into `.map` so that it actually calls the parent-function when clicking on a button?

I tried with an additional entry in the database, adding:

```
"_id": "60496f4e6478022895c0b1da",
"name": "Tim",
"imagepath": "./img/Tim.png",
"function": "props.doSomethingWithTim()"
```

and then map it with:

```
{props.people.map( result =>
  <PeopleComponent
  key={result._id}
  name={result.name}
  imagepath={result.imagepath}
  function={result.function}


  />)}
```

but then I get `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`
I passed down the function via props, and also tried to bind it in App.js with `this.props.doSomethingWithTim = this.props.doSomethingWithTim.bind(this)` but no idea what else I can try. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably find another way to do that, maybe by storing a simple value allowing you to pick the correct function to call ?

Maybe you can try using eval, but it's a really unsafe function ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```
function ParentPeopleComponent({people, doSomeStuff1, doSomeStuff2}) {
    return people.map(p =>
        <PeopleComponent
            // p={function: 'doSomeStuff1'}
            onSomething={() => eval(p.function)()}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you this helped me a lot. I added now an unique identifier on every db entry. then I send this value back to the parent function to know which component called the function.